# Batch file to determine if using Command Prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file

The last line in my batch file is `pause`. Is there any way to add a if condition to see if the script is run within command prompt or by double clicking to execute? I want to skip pause if it's running in command prompt.

```
...
...
if not RUN_IN_COMMAND_PROMPT (
  pause
)
```

EDIT:
Hope to find a solution works in Windows Server 2003/2008, WinXP, Win7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CALL :GETMYSWITCH %CMDCMDLINE%
IF /I "%MYSWITCH%" == "/C" ECHO I WAS STARTED IN THE EXPLORER & PAUSE
IF /I NOT "%MYSWITCH%" == "/C" ECHO I WAS STARTED IN A DOS SESSION


:GETMYSWITCH
SET MYSWITCH=%2
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a year later but for future people searching you can use

```
If /I "%COMSPEC%" == %CMDCMDLINE% Goto SkipPause
pause
:SkipPause
```

It will skip the pause block if running from the command line and pause if running from batch file.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a shell script is always going to be run in a "command prompt". But try using the `SESSIONNAME` env var - it seems to NOT be present if the script was started by double-clicking instead of manually running it from a prompt.

Comment: Tested under Win7, both (double-clicking, prompt) have %SESSIONNAME% value "Console".

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `SESSIONNAME` always contains `Console` regardless on how I start the batch file (using Windows XP)

Comment: Odd, on my Win7 64bit, sessionname is only present when I run the script from the prompt directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tty` command.

Use the -s option and check the return value.