# how to determine if *.bat file is running from console or on its own?

Tags: batch-file, console

Is there a way to check that so I can put a conditional at the end not to close console window or wait for user key press but omit that if *.bat file was typed from the keyboard in another console and there is no need to do that because windows wont close at the end ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `%CMDCMDLINE%` to check.

```
@echo off
CALL :GETMYSWITCH %CMDCMDLINE%
IF /I "%MYSWITCH%" == "/C" ECHO Used explorer & PAUSE
IF /I NOT "%MYSWITCH%" == "/C" ECHO used cmd

:GETMYSWITCH
SET MYSWITCH=%2
```

If it is the case that your batch file is being called from a script that you wrote rather than directly through a double-click, you can just have your script pass an argument to the batch file, then check for that to see if you need to `pause`.

Updated my answer to use this 'function' that I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6797358/2000557).

Comment: Don't work for me, in either case it has the same value. That is cmd/c... as if I doubleclicked it... maybe it is I have set the bat file as to run when I type a script file in console (trough assoc).. and in that case it is blind to how it was run

Comment: @rsk82 What OS are you using?

Comment: @rsk82 sorry to make  you try again, but can you try running that above just to see if it works?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed your edit. If a script is calling your batch file, then it wont be able to tell as far as I know. Have your script pass it a command line variable, and check for that.